# How to correctly output Plotly plots in shiny?

Tags: r, plotly, shiny, shinydashboard

I am trying to make a shiny app based on New York crime historical data. I am using single shiny page approach. Here's the data: https://data.world/data-society/nyc-crime-data

For some reason when I select the year to output the crime statistics, my output gets outputted only in the Viewer of RStudio and not on the main panel of the Shiny popup. Here's the complete code:

```
# Shiny App exploring New York City Crime Data between 2006-2016
# Data Source: https://data.world/data-society/nyc-crime-data

#########################Global Data######################

 # Data Reading
 set.seed(123)
 library("shiny")
 library("lubridate") 
 library("plotly")
 nypd<-read.csv("NYPD_Complaint_Data_Historic.csv")

 #Data Massaging
 nypd$year<-year(as.Date(nypd$RPT_DT,'%m/%d/%Y'))
 nypd$month<-month(as.Date(nypd$RPT_DT,'%m/%d/%Y'))
 nypd<-nypd[nypd$OFNS_DESC != "",]
 nypd2<-nypd[,c(1,6,8,14,16,17,22,23,25,26)]

 ui<-fluidPage(
 titlePanel("New York City Crime Data from 2006-2016"),
 sidebarLayout(
   sidebarPanel(
     sliderInput("year","Year of Crime",min=2006,max=2016,value=2008,step = 1)
   ),
   mainPanel(plotOutput("crimeplot"))
 )
 )


 server<-function(input,output){
   output$crimeplot<-renderPlot({

     nypd_yr_sorted<-nypd2[nypd2$year==input$year,]
     agg_data<-     aggregate(nypd_yr_sorted$CMPLNT_NUM,by=list(nypd_yr_sorted$OFNS_DESC),FUN=functi     on(x)length(unique(x)))
     colnames(agg_data)<-c("Crime","Crime count")
     bar_data<-agg_data[order(agg_data$`Crime count`, decreasing = TRUE),][1:5,]
     plot_ly(bar_data,x=~Crime,y=~`Crime count`,type="bar",color = ~Crime) %>% layout(xaxis= list(showticklabels = FALSE))
   })

 }

 shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: You're using a data file that is hundreds of MB in size. Can you copy and paste just a couple of rows to at least be able to reproduce your app without downloading that huge file?

Comment: @Phil - actually, it's 1.3gb, but what's a few hundred megabytes among friends?

Comment: @Piyush - were you able to make the changes listed in my answer and get your shiny app working?

Comment: @LenGreski Wow, I could not think about that. It was my first attempt at Shiny, so goes ok.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Plotly charts are rendered with `plotlyOutput()` and `renderPlotly()`. Two changes to the code are required:

1. Change `mainPanel()` to `mainPanel(plotlyOutput("crimeplot"))`
2. Change `output$crimeplot` to `output$crimeplot<-renderPlotly({`

...and the output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. It worked. But my visualization is not as good as yours: your bins are wider and colours are vivid. I am very curious to know how did you tweak them?

Comment: @PiyushVerma - I did not change any of the arguments in plot_ly() from the code you originally posted. What operating system are you using? I ran the chart on OS X. It's possible that some of the default settings vary by operating system.