# How to make interactive legends label using shiny?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

So, i'm starting to use shiny and making interactive plots.
So far, i've made my first and it looks like this:
[image]

The code that i used for this plot was

```
ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel("Suicide Numbers Per 100k"),
                sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(selectInput("region","Region",choices = unique(df$Country))),
                mainPanel(plotOutput("country100kplot"))))


server <- function(input,output){
  output$country100kplot <- renderPlot(df%>% filter(Country == input$region) %>% ggplot(aes(x=Year,y=Suicides_per_100k,colour=Generation))+geom_line()+labs(x="",y="Suicides",title = "")+theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)))
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Here, im only using dpyr,ggplot2 and shiny packages. We have a line plot for each generation ( and the user can select the country ), but the plot can be very noisy as you can see.

Say i only want to see the "Boomer" generation line; i would unmark all the other generation to see only this line plot. How can i do that?

EDIT: I tried to use ggplotly. It worked well for general plots. But i don't know why, it doesn't appear on the Shiny. The ggplotly only appears in my R Viewer, and on the shiny, it shows the original ggplot2 plot:
[image]

Comment: Try another more interactive library, like plotly. https://plotly.com/r/line-charts/. This may also help in terms of how to integrate into Shiny. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48017341/how-to-correctly-output-plotly-plots-in-shiny

Comment: Aww, there's no way to do it with ggplot2?

Comment: You can convert a ggplot into a plotly object, but IMO it doesn't always look great. Maybe take a look at the package `ggiraph`. It builds on ggplot2 and I think it looks pretty slick. I am not experienced enough with it to put in an answer on it.

Comment: Im having some issue. Check my edit

Comment: It may be that you need to use `plotly::renderPlotly()` instead of `renderPlot()`, but hard to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why this won't appear in Shiny with your current code is that you need to use a separate wrapper for plotly objects. I do not have access to the data you used but here is how I would adjust your code in order for this to work.

Main thing to note is the use of `plotlyOutput()` in the UI and `renderPlotly` in the Server section.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel("Suicide Numbers Per 100k"),
                sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(selectInput("region","Region",choices = unique(df$Country))),
                              mainPanel(plotlyOutput("country100kplot"))))


server <- function(input,output){
  output$country100kplot <- renderPlotly({
    
  g <-  df%>% 
      filter(Country == input$region) %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x=Year,y=Suicides_per_100k,colour=Generation))+
      geom_line()+
      labs(x="",y="Suicides",title = "")+
      theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
    
  g <- ggplotly(g)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```